# Ngx-chart height issue in Safari

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I have a problem with a `ngx-chart` in Safari. I have them with `height: 100%` so it fits the available space and I also set a `min-height` so it has at least a desired height.

This image taken in Firefox/Chrome:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzLV2.png) shows that it works on any other browser.

I'm probably doing something wrong but this is how it is shown on Safari in either Mac, iPhone or iPad: [iPhone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr9XQ.jpg)

Any ideas of what is going on? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `vh` (viewport height) unit in your `min-height` style as below,

```
<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 100vh">
...
</div>
```

Another option would be to use `calc()` as shown below,

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: calc(100%);">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but nope this did not fix it.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz repo? So we can see your code as well.

Comment: Fixed it using styles exclusively for Safari. Thank you anyways!